# "smaller or equal" sign in main item for the plot function in r

Tags: r, plot, expression

I would like to use expression or bquote to have the "smaller or equal" (≤) sign in the main of a plot.

Unfortunately my code throughs errors.

> Error: unexpected '<=' in "bq.FWGroup<-c(bquote("20cm "~ <="

Could you please help me with this issue.

```
FWGroup<-c("20cm <= Length < 30cm, 175g <= Weigth < 225g","20cm <= Length < 30cm, 225g <= Weigth < 275g",
           "30cm <= Length < 40cm, 200g <= Weigth < 250g","30cm <= Length < 50cm, 250g <= Weigth <= 300g")
Köder<-c("lebend","Atrappe")    

Versuche<-c(7,3,6,8,6,12,5)
Versuche<-cbind(Versuche,c(3,8,2,1,7,4,9))   
Group<-c(1,1,2,1,4,2,3)   
#for (i in 1:4)  {
# for (j in 1:2) {
i<-1; j<-1  
plot(1:7,Versuche[,1],
     type="n",
     main=paste(FWGroup[i],"Koeder:",Koeder[j],"_______________")) 
#bquote: 
bq.FWGroup<-c(bquote("20cm "~ <= ~" Length < 30cm, 175g" ~ <= ~ "Weigth < 225g"),bquote("20cm <= Length < 30cm, 225g <= Weigth < 275g"),bquote("30cm <= Length < 40cm, 200g <= Weigth < 250g"),bquote("30cm <= Length < 50cm, 250g <= Weigth <= 300g"))


plot(1:7,Versuche[,1],
     type="n",
     main=paste(bq.FWGroup[i],"Koeder:",Koeder[j],"_______________"))  

#exqpression:  
ex.FWGroup<-c(paste("20cm ", expression(<=), " Length < 30cm, 175g", expression(<=) , "Weigth < 225g"),"20cm <= Length < 30cm, 225g <= Weigth < 275g","30cm <= Length < 40cm, 200g <= Weigt < 250g","30cm <= Length < 50cm, 250g <= Weigth <= 300g")

ex.FWGroup<-c( expression(paste("20cm ", <=, " Length < 30cm, 175g", <= , "Weigth < 225g")),"20cm <= Length < 30cm, 225g <= Weigth < 275g", "30cm <= Length < 40cm, 200g <= Weigth < 250g","30cm <= Length < 50cm, 250g <= Weigth <= 300g")

plot(1:7,Versuche[,1],
     type="n",
     main=paste(ex.FWGroup[i],"Koeder:",Koeder[j],"_______________"))  
#  }
#  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R recognizes Unicode characters so just write the corresponding value in your title.

```
plot(iris$Sepal.Width ~ iris$Species, main = "3 \u2264 5")
```

[Main Title with ≤](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlHK5.png)